# How to populate column with every unique instance in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a bunch of data on users and the user's name will be in `Column A`. The user's will always be unique, but they may show up more than once. I want to have another  2 columns (say `E` and `F`) that will tally up names and how often they show up in that first column.

Is there an easy formulaic way to do this, or do I have to do it mostly by hand?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming row 1 is the headers, what you need is a basic `QUERY` formula in cell `E2`:

```
=QUERY(A2:A,"select A, count(A) where A<>'' group by A label count(A) ''")
```

You could also replace the condition `where A<>''` with `where A is not null`

```
=QUERY(A2:A,"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) ''")
```

Learn more about [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)